# How can I scale selected image iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

suppose I have selected image from image picker,and now I want to scale that image and want to set that scaled image in button or in any image view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you picking an image from picker, it should returt `UIImage` type. just set it as image to any UIView sublass (button are UIView sub class too):

```
[yourUIImageView setImage:UIImageFronUIPicker];
[yourUIButton setBackgroundImage:UIImageFronUIPicker];
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the `contentMode` property of the `UIImageView`.

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewContentModeScaleToFill,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit,
   UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill,
   UIViewContentModeRedraw,
   UIViewContentModeCenter,
   UIViewContentModeTop,
   UIViewContentModeBottom,
   UIViewContentModeLeft,
   UIViewContentModeRight,
   UIViewContentModeTopLeft,
   UIViewContentModeTopRight,
   UIViewContentModeBottomLeft,
   UIViewContentModeBottomRight,
} UIViewContentMode;
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement a `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` in your view controller and implement the delegate methods below

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {

    [selectedImageBtn setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[imagePicker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [[imagePicker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```